# HDFS Capacity: how to read "dfsadmin report"

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh

I am using Hadoop 2.6.0. When I run "hdfs  dfsadmin -report" I got something like this (simplified):

```
Configured Capacity: 3 TB
Present Capacity: 400GB
DFS Remaining: 300 GB
DFS Used: 100 GB
```

I am wondering what "configured capacity" is and what "present capacity" is. It looks like "Present Capacity" is the one in effect. How can I increase this?

Comment: This is answered very well at this link: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863570/where-does-the-hdfs-account-for-triple-replication-in-usage-reports

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configured Capacity is the total available capacity of the disks/voulmes used for data directory.

Eg: I've three 1TB disks mounted on `/Hadoop/sdb1, /Hadoop/sdc1, /Hadoop/sdd1` and I configured HDFS data directory on these volumes as `/Hadoop/sdb1/dfs/dn, /Hadoop/sdc1/dfs/dn, /Hadoop/sdd1/dfs/dn`, I also keep other non HDFS data in other directories in the same volume in `/Hadoop/sdb1/nonhadoop, /Hadoop/sdc1/nonhadoop, /Hadoop/sdd1/nonhadoop`, Size of data in the non hadoop directories is (800+900+900)GB.

Remaining space for HDFS will be (200+100+100)GB, Which will be the present capacity, Present capacity may vary depends on the usage of other Non HDFS directories in the same volume/disk, However configured capacity remains same until you add/remove volume/disks from HDFS.

Comment: Why would the Present capacity vary  ?

Comment: If the same is storage is used for services other than HDFS. HDFS present capacity may vary.